# How to override older ddl in database Oracle 12c SQL plus

Tags: sqlplus, oracle12c, ddl

I have generated ddl many times and have opened them in Oracle 12c SQL plus, however the latest one doesn't seem to override the older versions and I have tables and constraints which are not wanted as I have changed my relational model.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "override" actually mean? Could you provide an example?

Comment: sorry for not being specific but what i meant was that sql plus would get rid of the old ddl that i have imported and use the new one that i import. when using descibe table i seem to have table names that were not used in the new ddl generated.

Comment: Well, you'd get rid of old objects only if you dropped them (or, for stored procedures, views used CREATE **OR REPLACE**). Did you do that?

Comment: i tried getting rid of tables using drop command but there always seems to be a problem with the primary keys being used as foreign keys in another table. views did not work either